# How to loop over an array in an AWS Step Function?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I'm trying to process a DynamoDB query result, such as the `$.DDBResult` in a Map;

```
{
.
.
.,
"LookBackSeconds:"60",                     <-- variable based on request.
"OneMinuteAgo":"2023-08-14T15:59:00.000Z", <-- calculated via Lambda function using $.LookBackSeconds
"DDBResult": {
  "Count": 3,
  "Items": [
    {
      "Status": {
        "S": "ONLINE"
      },
      "Location": {
        "S": "North"
      },
      "LastValidationDateTime": {
        "S": "2023-08-14T14:55:55.144Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "Status": {
        "S": "ONLINE"
      },
      "Location": {
        "S": "South"
      },
      "LastValidationDateTime": {
        "S": "2023-08-14T14:55:54.890Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "Status": {
        "S": "ONLINE"
      },
      "Location": {
        "S": "East"
      },
      "LastValidationDateTime": {
        "S": "2023-08-14T14:55:52.968Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "ScannedCount": 3
}
}
```

I know that I can indicate that `$.DDBResult.Items` is the `ItemsPath`, but my problem is that in the map I need an addition data point, namely the current time minus some (calculated via a Lambda function using `$.LookBackSeconds`) to do some processing.  My thought was to loop over the `$.DDBResult.Items`, create a new array based on it's data and add to it `$.OneMinuteAgo`, but I can't find a way to loop over array to build another.

Does anyone have a thought on a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional [ItemSelector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-inline.html#itemselector) field lets you override the Map iterations' default (value only) input behaviour. Use it to add fields to the iteration input.

In your case, `ItemSelector` could reference array the element value (`$$.Map.Item.Value`) and the current time from the [context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map) object (note the double dollar sign prefix: `$$`). The seconds offset can be referenced from the input object (`$.LookBackSeconds`).

```json
"ItemSelector": {
    "ContextValue.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
    "Time.$": "$$.State.EnteredTime",
    "Seconds.$": "$.LookBackSeconds"
}
```

N.B.  The Map state's `ItemSelector` field replaces the deprecated `Parameters` field, which did the same thing.

Comment: that is brilliant!  Thank you.   I didn't realize that there was a context for the specific iteration within a Map.     I looked at the `ItemSelector` a bit but it's description is "...lets you modify items  .... and add static values if needed", and the word "static" made me think that JSONPath expressions weren't supported.  Thank you for the help and education!